# How to add a second source directory to an Eclipse project

Tags: c, eclipse

I have a C project in Eclipse that stores its files in two directories at the same level along with a bunch of other stuff that I do not need to have in the project.

```
/path/
     /code_I_want
     /bad_stuff/
     /more_code_i_want/
     /huge_pile_of_other_code/
```

Edit: The source directory is a Clearcase VOB mount point so I can't control what ends up there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Create a new C project in Eclipse.  You can give it its own directory at some arbitrary location in the filesystem, or you can point its folder at `code_I_want` or `more_code_i_want`.
2. Go under File, New, Folder.  Click the Advanced section and click "Link to folder in the file system."  This creates a virtual folder within your Eclipse project (similar to a symlink, if you're familiar with Linux / Unix) to whatever path you specify.  Use this to make `code_I_want` and/or `more_code_i_want` into virtual subdirectories of your Eclipse project.
3. Notice the Variables button there under the Advanced section?  That can be used to help create relative paths.  (For example, each of our developers sets a per-user variable called APP to point to their local working copy, then the Eclipse project settings can be shared between developers regardless of where they keep their working copies.)  To define variables, go under Windows, Preferences, General, Workspace, Linked Resources.

**Edit:**  Or you can just create symlinks.

Comment: im running linux btw. the symlink solution should work great!

Comment: I meant that you can use Eclipse to set up something like a symlink (and updated my answer accordingly).  But you're right, symlinks are a good, simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source > Add Folder

Comment: will this work if I am not using any builder and its not a Java project?

Comment: Good question, I must have missed the "C" part.  I haven't used C projects in Eclipse but I suspect that there will be a similar option.

Comment: I'm not finding anything that will let me add a path under the C++ builder options.

Answer (score 1):

New --> File --> Source Directory or Folder.

If you don't want files in the project, don't import them into eclipse and eclipse won't/shouldn't display them.

Comment: I should have included that its a clearcase vob and i dont import anything because importing into eclipse breaks clearcase plugin.

Comment: cant add a directory that is not already under the project root.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but it came up in a Google search I had on the same topic, and I think there is a better answer now: Using Eclipse/CDT, you can now add the root `/path/` provided in your example above which will automatically add the full tree to your Project Explorer.  The source files in the `code_i_want/` and `more_code_i_want/` folders will automatically be included in your builds at this point.

In order to exclude the `bad_stuff/` and `huge_pile_of_other_code/` folders from your build (but not your Project Explorer tree in Eclipse, which can be handy), simply right-click on each folder in the Project Explorer and choose `Resource Configurations->Exclude from build...` in the popup menu.  The icon in Project Explorer will be updated to reflect the source files in this folder will no longer be included in the build.

Even better, Eclipse allows you to specify code that you want to include in some build configurations but not in others, so you can manage build-specific code in this manner.

Comment: This works! in eclipse Luna, it's Select sub-folder in project explorer -> C/C++ Build -> Setting -> Exclude resource form buid